# HTML - Understanding automatically generated code from https://www.responsivebreakpoints.com - Web responsive images

Tags: html, responsive-design, auto-generate

I am trying to make a webpage with images that change their size depending of the window size. And I found the following website:
https://www.responsivebreakpoints.com

This website generates web-responsive HTML code when you upload the image you want responsive (while also cropping it and giving you all the different sizes).

I have been looking at the code, and I am struggling to understand it:

```
<picture>
      <source
      media="(max-width: 767px)"
      sizes="(max-width: 1534px) 100vw, 1534px"
      srcset="
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_1_1,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_50.jpg 50w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_1_1,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_656.jpg 656w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_1_1,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_893.jpg 893w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_1_1,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1121.jpg 1121w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_1_1,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1291.jpg 1291w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_1_1,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1452.jpg 1452w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_1_1,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1529.jpg 1529w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_1_1,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1534.jpg 1534w">
      <source
      media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)"
      sizes="(max-width: 1983px) 70vw, 1388px"
      srcset="
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_4_3,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_538.jpg 538w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_4_3,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_945.jpg 945w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_4_3,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1222.jpg 1222w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_4_3,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1349.jpg 1349w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_4_3,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1388.jpg 1388w">
      <source
      media="(min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)"
      sizes="(max-width: 2400px) 60vw, 1440px"
      srcset="
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_16_9,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_596.jpg 596w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_16_9,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1068.jpg 1068w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_16_9,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1398.jpg 1398w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_16_9,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1440.jpg 1440w">
      <img
      sizes="(max-width: 13688px) 40vw, 5475px"
      srcset="
            milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_480.jpg 480w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_1614.jpg 1614w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_2334.jpg 2334w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_2831.jpg 2831w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_3485.jpg 3485w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_4042.jpg 4042w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_4479.jpg 4479w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_4882.jpg 4882w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_5379.jpg 5379w,
            milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_5475.jpg 5475w"
      src="milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_5475.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

What is the difference between sizes and media? From what I understand, media="(max-width:767px)" is a condition, and the following code only happens if the window is less than 768px. If that is the case, what is the point of having an even higher amount of pixels in sizes?

Answer (score -1):

I have done some digging in Sublime Text 3, and found that that if the code is cleaned, the visual result is the same:

```
<picture>
    <source
    media="(max-width: 767px)"
    sizes="100vw"
    srcset="
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_1_1,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_50.jpg 50w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_1_1,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_656.jpg 656w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_1_1,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_893.jpg 893w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_1_1,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1121.jpg 1121w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_1_1,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1291.jpg 1291w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_1_1,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1452.jpg 1452w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_1_1,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1529.jpg 1529w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_1_1,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1534.jpg 1534w">
    <source
    media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)"
    sizes="70vw"
    srcset="
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_4_3,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_538.jpg 538w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_4_3,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_945.jpg 945w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_4_3,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1222.jpg 1222w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_4_3,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1349.jpg 1349w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_4_3,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1388.jpg 1388w">
    <source
    media="(min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)"
    sizes="60vw"
    srcset="
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_16_9,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_596.jpg 596w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_16_9,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1068.jpg 1068w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_16_9,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1398.jpg 1398w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_ar_16_9,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_1440.jpg 1440w">
    <img
    sizes="40vw"
    srcset="
        milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_480.jpg 480w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_1614.jpg 1614w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_2334.jpg 2334w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_2831.jpg 2831w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_3485.jpg 3485w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_4042.jpg 4042w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_4479.jpg 4479w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_4882.jpg 4882w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_5379.jpg 5379w,
        milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_5475.jpg 5475w"
    src="milkyway_a0ye1g_c_scale,w_5475.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

As you can see, sizes now has only the % of the screen that the image is going to use. The other parametres did nothing. I suppose, as is often the case in auto-generated code, that the extra stuff is useless and can be cleaned for smaller size.
Media is more restrictive and thus the parametres in sizes don't get looked at.